# Recreating an iOS App with the same Bundle ID, App name etc

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I'm not sure if this will be off-topic but I thought I might as well ask.

I currently have an iOS app in the App Store for an event that is held annually. Now that the event is over, I want to "close down" the app's features within a software update. (Removing access to certain areas of the app for example). However, I plan on re-using this app next year with the same layout as this year.

So, is there a way to either:

- Make a duplicate project and upload the "closed-down" version to the App Store as a software update for the current app (maintaining Bundle IDs, profiles, everything)

OR

- Can I create a brand new project and upload that?

I know this is unusual, but I'm a little confused. I want to avoid removing the app from the App Store. 
Thanks.

Comment: The Bundle ID *is the app* as far as the AppStore and devices are concerned. Either of your approaches will work; Modify existing source or create a whole new project.  Just be aware that your app must have minimum functionality or it is likely to be rejected during review.

Comment: Oh I see, so there shouldn't be a problem with duplicating the project, altering whatever I need, and archiving/submitting that one without altering any IDs or profiles or the like?

Comment: Exactly.  In the past I have replaced an earlier Objective-C app with a complete re-write in Swift.  As long as the Bundle ID and developer ID is the same, it is just like any other update.

Comment: If you want to leave an answer I'll mark it as the correct solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the whole app from the scratch and re-upload it.

As long as you have the same Bundle ID, AppStore will consider it the same app.

If you have access to your old Apple Developer account in iTunesConnect of cause.