# if we promote app using different technology . Do the user has to uninstall old App? or just update works?

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, app-store

we have developed app using ionic which is on live in playstore and app store, now we have completely rewritten app using reactnative, so if we promote app which is developed using react native, Do the user has to uninstall old App? or just update works?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that if it uses the same app identifier that it will just work for the user.
You can also see it here: [Recreating an iOS App with the same Bundle ID, App name etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452098/recreating-an-ios-app-with-the-same-bundle-id-app-name-etc)